# Pandas to_sql() performance - why is it so slow?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, singlestore

I am running into performance issues with Pandas and writing DataFrames to an SQL DB. In order to be as fast as possible I use [memSQL](http://www.memsql.com/) (it's like MySQL in code, so I don't have to do anything). I benchmarked my instance just now:

```
docker run --rm -it --link=memsql:memsql memsql/quickstart simple-benchmark
Creating database simple_benchmark
Warming up workload
Launching 10 workers
Workload will take approximately 30 seconds.
Stopping workload
42985000 rows inserted using 10 threads
1432833.3 rows per second
```

That isn't glorious, and it's just my local laptop. I know... I am also using the root user, but it's a throw-away Docker container.

Here is the code which writes my DataFrame to the DB:

```
    import MySQLdb

    import mysql.connector
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from pandas.util.testing import test_parallel

    engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root@localhost:3306/netflow_test', echo=False)
    # max_allowed_packet = 1000M in mysql.conf
    # no effect

    # @test_parallel(num_threads=8)
    def commit_flows(netflow_df2):
        % time netflow_df2.to_sql(name='netflow_ids', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False, chunksize=500)
    commit_flows(netflow_df2)
```

Below is the `%time` measurement of the function.

[Multi-threading](https://www.continuum.io/content/pandas-releasing-gil) does not make this faster. It remains within 7000 - 8000 rows/s.

> CPU times: user 2min 6s, sys: 1.69 s, total: 2min 8s Wall time: 2min
>   18s

Screenshot:
[image: memSQL shows the speed]

I also increased the `max_allowed_packet` size to commit in bulk, with a larger chunk size. Still not faster.

Here is the shape of the DataFrame:

```
netflow_df2.shape
(1015391, 20)
```

Does anyone know how I can make this faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someones gets a similar situation:

I removed SQlalchemy and used the (deprecated) MySQL flavor for Pandas' `to_sql()` function. The speedup is more than 120 %. I don't recommend to use this, but it works for me at the moment.

```
import MySQLdb

import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from pandas.util.testing import test_parallel

engine = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1","root","","netflow_test")

# engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root@localhost:3306/netflow_test', echo=False)

# @test_parallel(num_threads=8)
def commit_flows(netflow_df2):
    % time netflow_df2.to_sql(name='netflow_ids', flavor='mysql', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False, chunksize=50000)
commit_flows(netflow_df2)
```

If I find out how to convince memSQL to accept a large query (similar to MySQL's `max_allowed_packet = 1000M` in mysql.conf) I will be even faster. I should be able to hit more than 50000 rows per second here.

```
CPU times: user 28.7 s, sys: 797 ms, total: 29.5 s
Wall time: 38.2 s
```

126s before. 38.2s now.

Comment: MemSQL also has the max_allowed_packet setting - http://docs.memsql.com/docs/memsqlcnf.

Comment: I have been testing this, but it seems I also need to adapt some other variables. If I chose a bulk size of 60 000 I get SQL syntax errors back, and the query is cut.

Comment: Even using to_sql is quite slow. I have moved to duckdb https://github.com/cwida/duckdb. Reading and writing dataframe into it is blazingly fast. It is an embedded database though. Check it out to see if it meets your needs.